# Get the variable name that corresponds to the maximum value within an observation

Tags: max, stata

I need to find the variable name that corresponds to the highest value in each observation for a given variable list. I know that I can use `egen` to get the value itself:

```
egen newvar = rowmax(v1-vn)
```

But I don't know how to get the variable name corresponding to the highest value.

Comment: Technique for working rowwise in Stata is reviewed at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0046

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be other ways, but you can build on the `egen` results. Here is an example looping through the variables to find variable(s) with the maximum values.

```
// generate random data
clear
set obs 10
forval i=1/5    {
    gen r`i'=round(10*runiform())
}

egen maxval=rowmax(r1-r5)  // find maximum value
gen str20 maxvar="" // create string variable to store matched results

// find variables with the same value as maxval and add them to maxvar
foreach var of varlist r1-r5    {
    replace maxvar=maxvar+" "+"`var'" if maxval==`var'
}

list
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked great.Only for repeated values, is there a way to only keep the first one and ignore the rest?

Comment: Do you prefer to the use the first? ``replace maxvar="`var'" if maxval==`val'`` gives you the name of the last variable with the maximum.

Comment: For the first you can use ``replace maxvar = "`var'" if maxval==`var' & missing(maxvar)``.